# Using modal verbs correctly

Tags: modal-verbs

As far as I know we use "was able" on single occasion in the past and "could" when we are talking about repeated actions. But in the example below I can use both of them (taking on board that it's a negative sentense)? And what verb native would rather chose?

> She was ill that time and wasn't able to / couldn't phone (ring up, call).

Comment: That rule seems really odd. Where from did you get such rule? Anyway, what does "single occurrence" mean in the picture of your example sentence?

Comment: It's not a rule, or the rule isn't so simply stated.  *Before I hurt my leg, I {was able to|could} walk for many miles without a problem.*  and *I realized that I was able to|could reach him at the office*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that **was able to** fits well with contexts where the action is presented as an action that took place:

> The magician was able to free himself from the straight-jacket and received a great round of applause from the audience.

When we use **could** with such contexts (i.e. completed action) it sounds a little odd:

> The magician could free himself from the straight-jacket and received a great round of applause from the audience.

That sentence with **could** doesn't go well *if the meaning is that he freed himself.*

Slight changes present the action as one that was possible (and perhaps had been done before) but did not take place as of the temporal reference point in the past, making **could** viable:

> The magician could free himself from **a** straight-jacket. [he had that skill]
>
> The magician realized that by expelling all the air from his lungs, he could free himself from the straight-jacket.  [it would be possible]

**was able to** also works there.

The only limitation, then, is that **could** does not go well when the intended meaning involves an isolated action completed in the past.

With the negative, *there is no completed action*, and hence no conflict for **could**.  The reference is to an action impossible to complete in the past.

> She couldn't call because she was sick.
>
> She was unable to call because she was sick.

Comment: ok, I understood.